# how do I use JobLauncherSynchronizer in spring admin

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

There is an `@Aspect` that ensures that jobs in spring boot are not re-entrant. It is implemented in [JobLauncherSynchronizer.java](https://github.com/spring-attic/spring-batch-admin/blob/master/spring-batch-admin-manager/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/admin/launch/JobLauncherSynchronizer.java) and documented [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch-admin/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/admin/launch/JobLauncherSynchronizer.html). It is in the spring batch admin artifact.

My Job is created through a `@Bean` as follows:

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("synchronisationLauncher")
public JobLauncher synchronisationLauncher() throws Exception {
    SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
    jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
    jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor());
    jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
    return jobLauncher;
}
```

My question:
**how do I integrate the `@Aspect` into my JobLauncher?**

I naively tried to new it up, and set the properties in the method above, not surprisingly that didn't work very well. I was able to launch multiple instances.

My launch code is:

```
// dependencies from constructor.
// the launcher is qualified to 'synchronisationLauncher'
private JobLauncher launcher;
private Job mergeJob;
private JobQueryHelper jobQueryHelper;

@PostMapping("uri")
public ResponseEntity<APIResponse> SynchroniseRetailers()
        throws JobParametersInvalidException,
               JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException,
               JobRestartException,
               JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException {

    JobParametersBuilder builder = new JobParametersBuilder()
            .addLong("run.id", jobQueryHelper.findLastBatchExecutionIndex() + 1);
    launcher.run(mergeJob, builder.toJobParameters());
    return buildEmptyResponse();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you need such an aspect. The job launcher already checks if there is a running execution for the given job instance and throws a `JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException` if any. By default, spring batch won't allow you to run two concurrent executions of the same job instance at the same time. Can you elaborate on what you mean by "not re-entrant"?

Comment: the `JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException` is thrown when the same parameters are used to start the job, and it's already running. The exception doesn't help me though, because it is also thrown if the application dies, and the job finished unsuccessfully. It can then never be restarted with the same parameters again. I need to know if it's actually running, not if the last run was a fail. I have to manually alter the database to let it run again.

Comment: The aspect seems to actually check if the job is running, not if it ever ran in the past and didn't finish.

Comment: Getting a `JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException` because of a previous killed execution is another story. By default, the job launcher will check if there is a currently running execution and prevent you from starting another one (even if there are no previous killed executions). If you still need to double check before launching the job, see my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is override the `SimpleJobLauncher#run` method and add the double check before running the job:

```
@Bean
public JobLauncher jobLauncher(JobRepository jobRepository, JobExplorer jobExplorer) {
    SimpleJobLauncher simpleJobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher() {
        @Override
        public JobExecution run(Job job, JobParameters jobParameters) throws JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException, JobParametersInvalidException {
            Set<JobExecution> running = jobExplorer.findRunningJobExecutions(job.getName());
            if (!running.isEmpty()) {
                throw new JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException("An instance of this job is already active: " + job.getName());
            }
            return super.run(job, jobParameters);
        }
    };
    simpleJobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
    simpleJobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor());
    simpleJobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
    return simpleJobLauncher;
}
```

Note this is similar to the code in the aspect you shared but without needing any kind of AOP. As I mentioned in the comment, this check is already done in `super.run(job, jobParameters)`, so we are only adding a double check here.

Comment: thanks for the response, I think there are some nuances I am not appreciating here, so I will be careful before duplicating the check, but thanks very much!